# fuerte or diamondback

Tags: ros, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My project is currently running on electric, but I'm interested in trying the people library, which was released for diamondback, and just recently fuerte. Which version of it is recommended that I use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35357/fuerte-or-diamondback/) by [bwasserm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2506/bwasserm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-05-31**:
Which component of the people stack are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At this point, it's more likely that the Fuerte package will have better support and maintenance (because it's more recent).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bwasserm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2506/bwasserm/) on 2012-05-31**:
Thanks!